# php validating and authenticating strings

Tags: php, authentication

I have a couple of strings that make up a CustomerInfo Object.I want to write a function that authenticates each of those strings.

For instance I have the following values which are stored as strings:
apartment number
Street
City
Name
Telephone
Email

Each of these is received by the server and they need to be stored in a database. However, before I do that, I would like to authenticate the contents of the strings variables that carry these values.

I am new to PHP and server side programming in general. I was wondering what are some good and yet simple strategies to accomplish this.
Could someone point me to some ideas and links please.

Thanks

Comment: preg_match() et al comes to mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where regex is useful. Meet [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). You may want to read this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) on regular expressions :) And when you get good at them keep in mind that the can't do everything. They can only parse regular languages. Sometimes people get carried away and try to do too much with regex, so that's just a warning. Here's a simple example usage:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,5}$/i', $email)){
    // Email is unvalid.
    // Handle it here
}
```

The pattern`/^[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,5}$/i` can be broken down like:

/ --> Delimiter, any character can be used.

^ --> Start of the string

[\w.%+-]+ --> One or more (+) characters from the set [\w.%+-] which allows word characters (letters and underscores) and any of the symbols '.%+-'

@ --> A single @ sign

[\w.-]+ --> One or more word characters dots or hyphens

\. --> A single dot

[A-Z]{2,5} --> 2-5 capital letters

$ --> End of string

/ --> End delimeter (End of regular expression)

i --> Case-insensitive modifier (This means that where I had A-Z before will now also match a-z

Comment: Thanks a lot PaulPro. I appreciate your detailed answer and link. Its great to get me started.

Comment: Are there any other options besides regular expressions?

Comment: @user657514 There aren't many good solutions other than regex. You might be able to find a pre-made form validator or something, but it probably just uses regex anyways. Regex is just an easy way of searching for patterns in strings, which is what you need to do to validate them. You could iterate through them yourself if you want, but that's what regex simplifies for you into a PHP one liner :)

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I was just asking because, the data is coming from a mobile device and I was wondering if I should validate the data at the device level or at the server level or both.

Comment: @user657514 I recommend both, but that depends. The server side validation is the crucial one, for security reasons. The client side validation can make the user experience better since you can validate immediately and they can fix the errors without having to wait for a full page reload.

Answer (score 1):

In php you can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check your strings against [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html). If you want to use these but you are not familiar with regular expressions you could look at this [simple tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) or you could just search for a good regular expression in an [online regular expression database](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email) *(this example shows regular expressions used for [email pattern checking](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email))*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in PHP filters to perform standard validation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

```
// Example:
if (filter_var($email_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
    // Invalid e-mail!
}
```

Please note, this is only available for PHP 5.2+